# Is it possible to disable the pop up request?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to disable the pop-up option when in the chromes script editor that asks if you want to enable Chrome V8 (Alpha)? We have scripts that if we enable it, it breaks all our scripts and code we have in the editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, this is not possible. If your account has the V8 Rollout enabled, when opening the script it will show either this message or one that says that V8 is enabled.

If you find this too annoying to deal with, please consider submitting a feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/